# How can I update this kinect depth-basics code so that i can save raw depth data such as uint16 format in C#?

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk, depth, kinect-v2

I want to change this code so it can save raw depth data as uint16 format. but at this stage, it saves the image in uint8 format by converting the values 0-255. but i need to save the value as it come from camera or kinect such as uint16 format.

Code:depthBasics:

```
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <copyright file="MainWindow.xaml.cs" company="Microsoft">
//     Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
// </copyright>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.DepthBasics
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
    using Microsoft.Kinect;

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Map depth range to byte range
        /// </summary>
        private const int MapDepthToByte = 8000 ;

        /// <summary>
        /// Active Kinect sensor
        /// </summary>
        private KinectSensor kinectSensor = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Reader for depth frames
        /// </summary>
        private DepthFrameReader depthFrameReader = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Description of the data contained in the depth frame
        /// </summary>
        private FrameDescription depthFrameDescription = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Bitmap to display
        /// </summary>
        private WriteableBitmap depthBitmap = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Intermediate storage for frame data converted to color
        /// </summary>
        private byte[] depthPixels = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Current status text to display
        /// </summary>
        private string statusText = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the MainWindow class.
        /// </summary>
        public MainWindow()
        {
            // get the kinectSensor object
            this.kinectSensor = KinectSensor.GetDefault();

            // open the reader for the depth frames
            this.depthFrameReader = this.kinectSensor.DepthFrameSource.OpenReader();

            // wire handler for frame arrival
            this.depthFrameReader.FrameArrived += this.Reader_FrameArrived;

            // get FrameDescription from DepthFrameSource
            this.depthFrameDescription = this.kinectSensor.DepthFrameSource.FrameDescription;

            // allocate space to put the pixels being received and converted
            this.depthPixels = new byte[this.depthFrameDescription.Width * this.depthFrameDescription.Height];

            // create the bitmap to display
            this.depthBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(this.depthFrameDescription.Width, this.depthFrameDescription.Height, 96.0, 96.0, PixelFormats.Gray8, null);

            // set IsAvailableChanged event notifier
            this.kinectSensor.IsAvailableChanged += this.Sensor_IsAvailableChanged;

            // open the sensor
            this.kinectSensor.Open();

            // set the status text
            this.StatusText = this.kinectSensor.IsAvailable ? Properties.Resources.RunningStatusText
                                                            : Properties.Resources.NoSensorStatusText;

            // use the window object as the view model in this simple example
            this.DataContext = this;

            // initialize the components (controls) of the window
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// INotifyPropertyChangedPropertyChanged event to allow window controls to bind to changeable data
        /// </summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the bitmap to display
        /// </summary>
        public ImageSource ImageSource
        {
            get
            {
                return this.depthBitmap;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the current status text to display
        /// </summary>
        public string StatusText
        {
            get
            {
                return this.statusText;
            }

            set
            {
                if (this.statusText != value)
                {
                    this.statusText = value;

                    // notify any bound elements that the text has changed
                    if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                    {
                        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("StatusText"));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Execute shutdown tasks
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">object sending the event</param>
        /// <param name="e">event arguments</param>
        private void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.depthFrameReader != null)
            {
                // DepthFrameReader is IDisposable
                this.depthFrameReader.Dispose();
                this.depthFrameReader = null;
            }

            if (this.kinectSensor != null)
            {
                this.kinectSensor.Close();
                this.kinectSensor = null;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the user clicking on the screenshot button
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">object sending the event</param>
        /// <param name="e">event arguments</param>
        private void ScreenshotButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.depthBitmap != null)
            {
                // create a png bitmap encoder which knows how to save a .png file
                BitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();

                // create frame from the writable bitmap and add to encoder
                encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(this.depthBitmap));

                string time = System.DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("hh'-'mm'-'ss", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat);

                string myPhotos = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);

                string path = Path.Combine(myPhotos, "KinectScreenshot-Depth-" + time + ".png");

                // write the new file to disk
                try
                {
                    // FileStream is IDisposable
                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        encoder.Save(fs);
                    }

                    this.StatusText = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, Properties.Resources.SavedScreenshotStatusTextFormat, path);
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {
                    this.StatusText = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, Properties.Resources.FailedScreenshotStatusTextFormat, path);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the depth frame data arriving from the sensor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">object sending the event</param>
        /// <param name="e">event arguments</param>
        private void Reader_FrameArrived(object sender, DepthFrameArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            bool depthFrameProcessed = false;

            using (DepthFrame depthFrame = e.FrameReference.AcquireFrame())
            {
                if (depthFrame != null)
                {
                    // the fastest way to process the body index data is to directly access 
                    // the underlying buffer
                    using (Microsoft.Kinect.KinectBuffer depthBuffer = depthFrame.LockImageBuffer())
                    {
                        // verify data and write the color data to the display bitmap
                        if (((this.depthFrameDescription.Width * this.depthFrameDescription.Height) == (depthBuffer.Size / this.depthFrameDescription.BytesPerPixel)) &&
                            (this.depthFrameDescription.Width == this.depthBitmap.PixelWidth) && (this.depthFrameDescription.Height == this.depthBitmap.PixelHeight))
                        {
                            // Note: In order to see the full range of depth (including the less reliable far field depth)
                            // we are setting maxDepth to the extreme potential depth threshold
                            ushort maxDepth = ushort.MaxValue;

                            // If you wish to filter by reliable depth distance, uncomment the following line:
                            //// maxDepth = depthFrame.DepthMaxReliableDistance

                            this.ProcessDepthFrameData(depthBuffer.UnderlyingBuffer, depthBuffer.Size, depthFrame.DepthMinReliableDistance, maxDepth);
                            depthFrameProcessed = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (depthFrameProcessed)
            {
                this.RenderDepthPixels();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Directly accesses the underlying image buffer of the DepthFrame to 
        /// create a displayable bitmap.
        /// This function requires the /unsafe compiler option as we make use of direct
        /// access to the native memory pointed to by the depthFrameData pointer.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="depthFrameData">Pointer to the DepthFrame image data</param>
        /// <param name="depthFrameDataSize">Size of the DepthFrame image data</param>
        /// <param name="minDepth">The minimum reliable depth value for the frame</param>
        /// <param name="maxDepth">The maximum reliable depth value for the frame</param>
        private unsafe void ProcessDepthFrameData(IntPtr depthFrameData, uint depthFrameDataSize, ushort minDepth, ushort maxDepth)
        {
            // depth frame data is a 16 bit value
            ushort* frameData = (ushort*)depthFrameData;

            // convert depth to a visual representation
            for (int i = 0; i < (int)(depthFrameDataSize / this.depthFrameDescription.BytesPerPixel); ++i)
            {
                // Get the depth for this pixel
                ushort depth = frameData[i];

                // To convert to a byte, we're mapping the depth value to the byte range.
                // Values outside the reliable depth range are mapped to 0 (black).
                this.depthPixels[i] = (byte)(depth >= minDepth && depth <= maxDepth ? (depth / MapDepthToByte) : 0);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Renders color pixels into the writeableBitmap.
        /// </summary>
        private void RenderDepthPixels()
        {
            this.depthBitmap.WritePixels(
                new Int32Rect(0, 0, this.depthBitmap.PixelWidth, this.depthBitmap.PixelHeight),
                this.depthPixels,
                this.depthBitmap.PixelWidth,
                0);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the event which the sensor becomes unavailable (E.g. paused, closed, unplugged).
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">object sending the event</param>
        /// <param name="e">event arguments</param>
        private void Sensor_IsAvailableChanged(object sender, IsAvailableChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // on failure, set the status text
            this.StatusText = this.kinectSensor.IsAvailable ? Properties.Resources.RunningStatusText
                                                            : Properties.Resources.SensorNotAvailableStatusText;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private unsafe void ProcessDepthFrameData(IntPtr depthFrameData, uint depthFrameDataSize, ushort minDepth, ushort maxDepth)
        {
           // CONVERT IN TO ANY VALID FORMAT YOU WANT
           // THEN HERE YOU HAVE DEPTH DATA ARRAY, SAVE IT AS YOU LIKE
            ushort* frameData = (ushort*)depthFrameData;

        }
```

If you need more efficiency, you can try something like

```
 depthFrame.CopyFrameDataToBuffer(buffer);
```

In `Reader_FrameArrived` function.

Comment: not works sir. full black. i read it in matlab . all values are zero

Comment: How did you write into the file?

Answer (score 0):

The example provided in the Kinect SDK saves the PNG's in 8-bit format (0-255) therefore you loose the depth values. The issue is that WPF(?) cannot display 16-bit image data on screen (i believe due to GDI+ restrictions as mentioned [in another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26722231/6799468))
To save the depth images as Raw 16-bit PNG's; a couple of things need to be done.

1. WriteableBitmap item with PixelFormats.Gray16 needs to be declared, instead of the PixelFormats.Gray8
2. Two separate WritePixels need to be called, one for displaying the image in (byte)  format and another for saving the depth image in 16-bit (ushort) format
3. Lastly, the depth data acquired needs to be processed twice, once in a byte array for displaying on screen, and once in ushort array for saving.

Note that the above can be modified as required (or for performance reasons if req) but for me, this works just fine and i can display the depth images and save the raw depth data aswell.

The code is as follows:

Initialize a new var:

```
    private ushort[] raw = null;
    private WriteableBitmap rawPNG = null;
```

In **MainWindow** Create two writeableBitmap's

```
this.depthBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(this.depthFrameDescription.Width, this.depthFrameDescription.Height, 96.0, 96.0, PixelFormats.Gray8, null);
this.rawPNG= new WriteableBitmap( this.depthFrameDescription.Width, this.depthFrameDescription.Height, 96.0, 96.0, PixelFormats.Gray16, null );
```

In **ProcessDepthFrameData** assign the values:

```
// FOR DISPLAYING ON SCREEN:
// To convert to a byte, we're mapping the depth value to the byte range.
// Values outside the reliable depth range are mapped to 0 (black).
this.depthPixels[i] = (byte)(depth >= minDepth && depth <= maxDepth ? (depth / MapDepthToByte) : 0);

// FOR SAVING RAW PNG 16-BIT DATA
// Keeping the raw depth values after clipping them to the max depth. The data is converted to ushort which is 16bit data
raw[i] = (ushort)(depth >= minDepth && depth <= maxDepth ? (depth) : 0);
```

In **RenderDepthPixels**, create teh two images:

```
// Rendering frame for displaying on the screen, in 8-Bit grayscale format
    depthBitmap.WritePixels(
            new Int32Rect( 0, 0, depthBitmap.PixelWidth, depthBitmap.PixelHeight ),
            depthPixels,
            depthBitmap.PixelWidth,
            0 );

// Rendering frame for saving as raw-16-bit PNG file
    rawPNG.WritePixels(
            new Int32Rect( 0, 0, depthBitmap.PixelWidth, depthBitmap.PixelHeight ),
            raw,
            depthBitmap.PixelWidth * 2,
            0 );
```

And lastly, in **ScreenshotButton_Click**, save the file:

```
// TO SAVE THE DISPLAYED 8-BIT PNG
//encoder.Frames.Add( BitmapFrame.Create( this.depthBitmap) );

// TO SAVE THE RAW 16-BIT PNG
encoder.Frames.Add( BitmapFrame.Create( this.rawPNG ) );
```

The results can be verified by loading the depth image in Matlab. Imread shows a Uint16 image format and the depth values are retained in the matrix. Or by just checking the png file properties :)

I have shared the complete code that is working for me at [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/jveEZKWN). Hopefully it should work for you aswell, and solves the issue.

Comment: Glad to know it works fine. In addition, to improve performance, you can call the required parts in ProcessDepthFrameData  and RenderDepthPixels only when the Screenshot button is clicked. 

Also, please always upvote the correct answers so they may be of use to others aswell.