# How can I convert an ushort 16 bit array to an image C#

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, pixelformat, ushort

I have a 16 bit ushort array with values ranging from 0 to 65535  which I want to convert into a grayscale Image to save. What I tried doing was write the values into an image data type and then converting the image to a bitmap, but as soon as I put it into the bitmap data type it gets converted to 8 bit data.

```
using (Image<Gray, ushort> DisplayImage2 = new Image<Gray, ushort>(Width, Height))
{
    int Counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Width; j++)
        {
            DisplayImage.Data[i, j, 0] = ushortArray[Counter];
            Counter++;
        }
    }
    Bitmap bitt = new Bitmap(Width, Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale);
    bitt = DisplayImage2.ToBitmap();
    bitt.Save(SaveDirectory, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff);)
}
```

As soon as the image gets put into the bitmap bitt it gets changed to 8 bit, is there a way of doing this? Thank you

Comment: I know, that's why I tried saving it as a 24bit too, but it ends up as 8 bit at the end too.

Comment: Show where you get this array, if it has any headings, any specific format.

Comment: The array comes from a camera frame grab and it is just values between 0 and 65535 nothing else.

Comment: It doesn't have to be tiff, just any file format that supports 16bit images.

Comment: Camera image is probably raw format, it has nothing to do with 16-bit bitmap format. 16-bit bitmap format is old and it loses color information.

Comment: 16-bit bitmap format is either RGB565 or RGB555, it's old and is not used in modern applications. You can store grayscale in 16-bit but that's less efficient than storing grayscale in 8-bit format. Show some information about your camera and print the first bytes in the source image.

Comment: Apparently there is a way to save a 16bit grayscale bitmap as TIFF after all: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40179536/555045

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapting from the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40179536/555045) on how to store a `Format16bppGrayScale` bitmap as TIFF, but without creating the actual bitmap first. This requires some .NET dlls that you may not usually add as references, namely PresentationCore and WindowsBase.

The `BitmapSource` necessary to construct the `BitmapFrame` that the TIFF encoder can encode can be created straight from an array, so:

```
var bitmapSrc = BitmapSource.Create(Width, Height, 96, 96,
                                    PixelFormats.Gray16, null, rawData, Width * 2);
TiffBitmapEncoder encoder = new TiffBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Compression = TiffCompressOption.Zip;
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSrc));
encoder.Save(outputStream);
```

When I tried this, the file seemed to be a real 16bit image.