# Acess Violation Exception When saving a Bitmap

Tags: c#, exception, bitmap, grayscale, pixelformat

I need to save a intraoral x-ray image, I'm try to use the 8bppIndexed pixel format, and using this code to save:

```
 private void SaveImage(short[] data, int widht, int height)
        {
            try
            {
                Bitmap pic = new Bitmap(widht, height, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

                Rectangle dimension = new Rectangle(0, 0, pic.Width, pic.Height);
                BitmapData picData = pic.LockBits(dimension, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, pic.PixelFormat);

                IntPtr pixelStartAddress = picData.Scan0;

                Marshal.Copy(data, 0, pixelStartAddress, data.Length);

                pic.UnlockBits(picData);

                pic = ConvertToGrayscale(pic);

                pic.Save("C:\\Users\\WIM\\Desktop\\teste\\teste\\teste.jpeg");
                pic.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
```

And with this line `Marshal.Copy(data, 0, pixelStartAddress, data.Length);` I receive the AcessViolationException.

I'm not used to c# so I really don't undertand why I got this error. What I read is that maybe the ptr has been in use, but if I use other pixelFormat, like 16bppRgb565, I can capture the image and transform to grayScale, but the image return deformed. [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rOrh.jpg)

I'm using an array of short because It's the data I received from the sdk I received from the company we bought the sensor;

In my researches, I found the 16bppGrayScale is a good option, but the GDI+ don't have it encoded yet. But we can make a DICOM for this, but we need to run the application on nootbooks with a hardware not that good, so for that I'm trying to use the 8bppIndexed pixel format.

Comment: This is the exception descirption: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.accessviolationexception?view=net-5.0 That is basically the _OS Memory Protection_ stopping the classes unmanaged code. | I bet the class uses unamanged code under the hood. And you are not following the proper order of funciton calls. But I do not know this class enough to know for certain.

Comment: @Christopher for now I just call this SaveImage on the end of the method of acquirance of the x-ray. So I don't know much about unmanaged and managed code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dicided to answer my own question to make the post more easy to read.

I managed to find a solution through this post: [Generate 16-bit grayscale BitmapData and save to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26721809/generate-16-bit-grayscale-bitmapdata-and-save-to-file)

So please vote on the answer to make more people find the solution more easily.

And the code I'm using now is like this now:

```
       private void SaveImage(short[] data, int widht, int height)
        {
            try
            {
                Bitmap pic = new Bitmap(widht, height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale);

                Rectangle dimension = new Rectangle(0, 0, pic.Width, pic.Height);
                BitmapData picData = pic.LockBits(dimension, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, pic.PixelFormat);

                IntPtr pixelStartAddress = picData.Scan0;

                //Marshal.Copy(data, 0, pixelStartAddress, data.Length);
                Marshal.Copy(data, 0, pixelStartAddress, data.Length);

                pic.UnlockBits(picData);


                //SaveBmp(pic, Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "imagem"));

                SaveBmp(pic, "C:\\Users\\WIM\\Desktop\\teste\\teste\\teste.bmp");
                pic.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }

        private static void SaveBmp(Bitmap bmp, string path)
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);

            BitmapData bitmapData = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);

            var pixelFormats = ConvertBmpPixelFormat(bmp.PixelFormat);

            BitmapSource source = BitmapSource.Create(bmp.Width,
                                                      bmp.Height,
                                                      bmp.HorizontalResolution,
                                                      bmp.VerticalResolution,
                                                      pixelFormats,
                                                      null,
                                                      bitmapData.Scan0,
                                                      bitmapData.Stride * bmp.Height,
                                                      bitmapData.Stride);

            bmp.UnlockBits(bitmapData);


            FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);

            TiffBitmapEncoder encoder = new TiffBitmapEncoder();

            encoder.Compression = TiffCompressOption.Zip;
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(source));
            encoder.Save(stream);

            stream.Close();
        }


        private static System.Windows.Media.PixelFormat ConvertBmpPixelFormat(System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat pixelformat)
        {
            System.Windows.Media.PixelFormat pixelFormats = System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Default;

            switch (pixelformat)
            {
                case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb:
                    pixelFormats = PixelFormats.Bgr32;
                    break;

                case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed:
                    pixelFormats = PixelFormats.Gray8;
                    break;

                case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale:
                    pixelFormats = PixelFormats.Gray16;
                    break;
            }

            return pixelFormats;
        }
```

So now we change the 16bppGrayScale to Gray16.

To use that, you will need to add the reference to the "PresentationCore" on your project.

That you can use then

```
System.Windows.Media.Format
```

And anothers objects like `BitmapSource`.

Answer (score 1):

1. `short[] data` the type of data is `short`, while it should be `byte[]`
2. but I think what actually causing the problem is: `data.Length` should be equal to `picData.Stride * pic.Height` and in your case, it looks like it is not.

Comment: I still got the Acess Violaton exception

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that you are dealing with unmanaged code. The other is that the exception handling is *extremely* questionable.

```
try
        {
            Bitmap pic = new Bitmap(widht, height, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

            Rectangle dimension = new Rectangle(0, 0, pic.Width, pic.Height);
            BitmapData picData = pic.LockBits(dimension, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, pic.PixelFormat);

            IntPtr pixelStartAddress = picData.Scan0;

            Marshal.Copy(data, 0, pixelStartAddress, data.Length);

            pic.UnlockBits(picData);

            pic = ConvertToGrayscale(pic);

            pic.Save("C:\\Users\\WIM\\Desktop\\teste\\teste\\teste.jpeg");
            pic.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
```

There are a number of issues in that code:

**Use of Disposeable resoruces without using**

The code uses the class Bitmap which needs disposing, but forgoes the [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement). while there is a call to Dispose(), it will **not** be executed in a exception case. Using is there for that precise

**Catching Exception**

Catching Exception for anything but logging and letting it go on to kill the process, is a deadly sin of Exception handling. Swallowing anything but a Vexing or Exogenous exception sets you up for more and less undertanable followup exceptions.

There are two articles on proper exception handling I would advise you to read. They explain the things much better then I could:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/
- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Ignoring any exception can cause more and less understandable follwup errors. Especially if you ignore errors regarding Arrays, you can easily cause a Access Violation Exception.

Note that a Access Violation Exception is good example for a Fatal Exception itself. If you have one, it is safer to let the process die!

```
using(Bitmap pic = new Bitmap(widht, height, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed)){

    Rectangle dimension = new Rectangle(0, 0, pic.Width, pic.Height);
    BitmapData picData = pic.LockBits(dimension, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, pic.PixelFormat);

    IntPtr pixelStartAddress = picData.Scan0;

    Marshal.Copy(data, 0, pixelStartAddress, data.Length);

    pic.UnlockBits(picData);

    pic = ConvertToGrayscale(pic);

    pic.Save("C:\\Users\\WIM\\Desktop\\teste\\teste\\teste.jpeg");
}
```

Asuming the Access Violation was not caused by ignoring another Exception:

These 3 lines are the unamanaged code:

```
    IntPtr pixelStartAddress = picData.Scan0;

    Marshal.Copy(data, 0, pixelStartAddress, data.Length);

    pic.UnlockBits(picData);
```

I try to avoid unmanaged code so I can not truly help you debugging it. But I noticed that you use `data` twice - but it seems not defined anywhere in this code.

Comment: I will read the links you send. Thank you for the explanation. And `data` is a parameter