# Why are bmps stored upside down?

Tags: windows, image, legacy, bmp

Why are BMP images stored upside down and zero-padded so they are four-byte aligned?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why must "stride" in the System.Drawing.Bitmap constructor be a multiple of 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185944/why-must-stride-in-the-system-drawing-bitmap-constructor-be-a-multiple-of-4)

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q81498/   claims the upsidedownness is an artifact of being backwards compatible with Presentation Manager, which means it's something that IBM did for OS/2.

Comment: They are upside-down for compatibility with OS/2 Presentation Manager.  It can actually be either, top line first bitmaps have a negative height.

Comment: @HansPassant, the ability to have a negative height is a feature added well after the bitmap format was popularized.

Comment: Guys settle the negative height argument this BMP browser drop-in/png/jpg universal "uncompressed" replacement library ain't gonna write itself!!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Here's a quote from Petzold:

> So, in DIBs, the bottom row of the image is the first row of the file,
>   and the top row of the image is the last row in the file. This is
>   called a bottom-up organization. Because this organization is
>   counterintuitive, you may ask why it's done this way.
>
> Well, it all goes back to the OS/2 Presentation Manager. Someone at
>   IBM decided that all coordinate systems in PM—including those for
>   windows, graphics, and bitmaps—should be consistent. This provoked a
>   debate: Most people, including programmers who have worked with
>   full-screen text programming or windowing environments, think in terms
>   of vertical coordinates that increase going down the screen. However,
>   hardcore computer graphics programmers approach the video display from
>   a perspective that originates in the mathematics of analytic geometry.
>   This involves a rectangular (or Cartesian) coordinate system where
>   increasing vertical coordinates go up in space.
>
> In short, the mathematicians won. Everything in PM was saddled with a
>   bottom-left origin, including window coordinates. And that's how DIBs
>   came to be this way.

**Source**: Charles Petzold, *Programming for Windows 5th Edition*, Chapter 15.

Comment: Interesting that they kept this representation for DIBs but changed it for window coordinates, reintroducing the inconsistency.

Answer (score -5):

They are stored accordingly to a display coordinate system. (0, 0) is at the upper left corner. X (corresponds to width) goes from left to right. Y (corresponds to height) goes from up to bottom.

As for "4 Byte question" see [Why must "stride" in the System.Drawing.Bitmap constructor be a multiple of 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185944/why-must-stride-in-the-system-drawing-bitmap-constructor-be-a-multiple-of-4)

Comment: No they aren't. BMPs are stored from bottom to top, left to right.