# After writing BMP file, image is flipped upside down

Tags: c++, xcode, image, opengl, bmp

I am using the following code:

```
f = fopen( _stringhelper.STR("%s.bmp", filename), "wb" );
if( !f ) {
    _core.Error( ERC_ASSET, "ncImageLoader::CreateImage - Couldn't create %s image.\n", filename );
    return false;
}

int w = width;
int h = height;
int i;

int filesize = 54 + 3 * w * h;

byte bmpfileheader[14] = {
    'B', 'M',
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0,
    0, 0,
    54, 0, 0, 0 };

byte bmpinfoheader[40] = { 40, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    1, 0,
    24, 0};

byte bmppad[3] = { 0, 0, 0 };

bmpfileheader[2] = (byte)( filesize );
bmpfileheader[3] = (byte)( filesize >> 8 );
bmpfileheader[4] = (byte)( filesize >> 16 );
bmpfileheader[5] = (byte)( filesize >> 24 );

bmpinfoheader[4] = (byte)( w );
bmpinfoheader[5] = (byte)( w >> 8);
bmpinfoheader[6] = (byte)( w >> 16  );
bmpinfoheader[7] = (byte)( w >> 24);
bmpinfoheader[8] = (byte)( h );
bmpinfoheader[9] = (byte)( h >> 8 );
bmpinfoheader[10] = (byte)( h >> 16 );
bmpinfoheader[11] = (byte)( h >> 24 );

fwrite( bmpfileheader, 1, 14, f );
fwrite( bmpinfoheader, 1, 40, f );

for( i = 0; i < h; i++ ) {
    fwrite( data + ( w * (h - i - 1) * 3 ), 3, w, f );
    fwrite( bmppad, 1, ( 4 - ( w * 3 ) % 4 ) % 4, f );
}

fclose(f);
```

I am using `glReadPixels()` to capture the display data. If I go to the folder where I saved this file and open it - it's fine, color palette is good, but it is flipped upside down. I've tried to write the for loop "backwards" but still nothing.. I don't get it.

What may be the problem?

Comment: Can you show your backwards `for` loop? (The current one is actually "backwards" but that's because BMP expects it.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bitmaps are stored "upside-down", see more about that here:

[Why are bmps stored upside down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8346115/why-are-bmps-stored-upside-down)

You could set the height as a negative value to have it displayed correctly. (**-height**)

From **[MSDN site,  BITMAPINFOHEADER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318229(v=vs.85).aspx)**:

> If **biHeight** is negative, the bitmap is a top-down DIB with the
> origin at the upper left corner.

Answer (score 3):

### BMP File Format Structure

[image: BMP File Format]

- For uncompressed RGB bitmaps, if Height is **positive**, the bitmap is
  a bottom-up DIB(device-independent bitmap) with the origin at the lower left corner.
  [image: BottomUP]
- If Height is **negative**, the bitmap is a top-down DIB with the origin
  at the upper left corner.
  [image: TopDown]
- For YUV bitmaps, the bitmap is always top-down, regardless of the sign
  of Height. Decoders should offer YUV formats with positive
  Height, but for backward compatibility they should accept YUV
  formats with either positive or negative Height.
- For compressed formats, Height must be positive, regardless of
  image orientation.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-bitmapinfoheader?redirectedfrom=MSDN