# Cannot convert YUV420 frame to Bitmap

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, bitmap

I am trying to convert YUV420 frames to Bitmap or Image. I am reading these frames from an MP4 video in C# using the AVBlocks library. So, after creating an input and output socket using AVBlocks classes, I then pull each frame from the video with a YUV420 color format and UncompressedVideo stream type. I basically do this by calling `Transcoder.Pull(int outputIndex, MediaSample outputData)` and then the MediaBuffer that's part of the outputData has the data in an array of bytes. So I am trying to convert these bytes to a Bitmap or Image so that I can eventually show each frame into a PictureBox in the Winforms application.

What I've tried:

I have tried using a MemoryStream, as shown below, but I get an unhandled ArgumentException saying that the parameter is not valid. I tried using `ImageConverter()` as well to convert to an Image, but I get the same exception. Then, I converted the byte array from YUV to RGB format and gave the updated array as a parameter to the MemoryStream, but again no luck. I also tried changing the color format of the output socket from YUV420 to a BGR format, but it resulted in the same issue as above. The code that tries to convert to a bitmap using MemoryStream:

```
while (transcoder.Pull(out inputIndex, yuvFrame))
{
    buffer = (MediaBuffer) yuvFrame.Buffer.Clone();
    Bitmap b;

    byte[] temp = new byte[buffer.DataSize];
    Array.Copy(buffer.Start, buffer.DataOffset, temp, 0, buffer.DataSize);
    var ms = new MemoryStream(temp);
    b = new Bitmap(ms);
}
```

The aforementioned exception is thrown in the last line of the code. I'm not sure if it's the color format or the stream type, or something else that's causing the problem. If someone wants to see more of the code (setting up input & output sockets etc), let me know. For reference, the link to the example I've been following from AVBlocks is [this](http://wiki.avblocks.com/avblocks-programming/using-transcoder/using-as-a-decoder/h-264-decoder) and the link to MediaBuffer class is [this](http://doc.avblocks.com/net/latest/class_primo_software_1_1_a_v_blocks_1_1_media_buffer.html#a69e027b75a77261e41fedf1b7d645a8c).

Comment: The `MemoryStream` argument does not expect raw RGB data. It expects bytes of a known file format, like png, jpeg, bmp, gif etc.

Answer (score 1):

The `Bitmap(MemoryStream ms)` constructor expects the bytes from *an actual file*, like a png, jpeg, bmp or gif. If I'm reading this correctly, you don't have that; you only have  pure RGB triplets data. That isn't enough, because it lacks all information about the image's width, height, colour depth etc.

You will need to actually construct an image object from the RGB data. This isn't really trivial; it means you need to make a new image object with the correct dimensions and colour format, then access its backing bytes array, and write your data into it. The actual code for creating an image out of a byte array can be found [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43967594/395685).

Note that you'll have to take into account the actual stride in the resulting data you get; the amount of bytes on each line of the image. Images are saved per line, and those lines are usually padded to a multiple of 4 bytes. This obviously messes up a lot if you don't take it into account.

If your data is completely compact, then the `stride` to give to the `BuildImage` function I linked to will just be your image width multiplied by the amount of bytes per pixel (should be 3 for 24bpp RGB), but if not, you'll have to pad it to the next multiple of 4.