# Convert from 8-bit indexed pixel array to Bitmap Object

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, bitmap, bmp

I am developing a program which gets Image from a Camera device. Here is the event how I get the Image.

```
    private void StreamGrabber_ImageGrabbed(object sender, ImageGrabbedEventArgs e)
    {
        IGrabResult res = e.GrabResult;
        byte[] pixels = res.PixelData as byte[];
        pictureBox1.Image = ByteArrayToBitmap(pixels,res.Width,res.Height, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

        //ImagePersistence.Save(ImageFileFormat.Jpeg, "tmp/tmp" + i + ".jpg", img);

    }
```

I can get the Pixel Data Array with the code above. And I can directly save the image with the single line of code.

```
ImagePersistence.Save(ImageFileFormat.Jpeg, "tmp/tmp" + i + ".jpg", img);
```

Now my problem starts here. I don't want to save it, I just want to create the Bitmap object from pixel data and simply show in my pictureBox1 object.
I have pixel data of image but in any case I couldn't get the image correctly.

Here is ByteArrayToBitmap function;

```
    public Bitmap ByteArrayToBitmap(byte[] byteIn, int imwidth, int imheight, PixelFormat pixelformat)     
    {
        Bitmap picOut = new Bitmap(imwidth, imheight, pixelformat);  
        BitmapData bmpData = picOut.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, imwidth, imheight), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, pixelformat);
        IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
        Int32 psize = bmpData.Stride * imheight;
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(byteIn, 0, ptr, psize);
        picOut.UnlockBits(bmpData);
        return picOut;      
    }
```

And here is How image looks like;

[image: GRABBED IMAGE IS HERE]

As you can see, image is weird. First I thought if it is the camera's problem. But I have tried it with it's own program, Camera works perfectly. Something going wrong on my code.

I am giving useful informations from debug screen;

The image dimension is 3840x2748.

The size of byte array of pixel data is 10.552.320

I have made that calculation: 3840*2748 = 10.552.320 
The image is not grayscale, it is RGB image,

So I Thought that pixel data includes 8-bit-indexed pixel.

I am stuck with this problem.
I have tried to give you all useful information about my problem.

How can I get the image and create bitmap object correctly ?

**EDIT**

```
    public Bitmap CopyDataToBitmap(int Width, int Height, byte[] data)
    {
        var b = new Bitmap(Width, Height, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
        ColorPalette ncp = b.Palette;
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 32; i <= 256; i+=32) //for R channel (3 bit)
            for (int j = 32; j <= 256; j+=32)  //for G Channel (3 bit)
                for (int k = 64; k <= 256; k+=64)  //for B Channel (2 bit)
                {
                    ncp.Entries[counter] = Color.FromArgb(255,i-1,j-1,k-1);
                    counter++;
                }
        b.Palette = ncp;

        var BoundsRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height);

        BitmapData bmpData = b.LockBits(BoundsRect,
                                        ImageLockMode.WriteOnly,
                                        PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

        IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
        int bytes = bmpData.Stride * b.Height;
        var rgbValues = new byte[bytes];
        Marshal.Copy(data, 0, ptr, bytes);

        b.UnlockBits(bmpData);
        Console.WriteLine(b.GetPixel(3648, 1145).ToString());

        return b; 
    }
```

I have changed algorithm with that function. I am using color palette. But result is still same.

```
        ColorPalette ncp = b.Palette;
        for (int i = 0; i < 257; i++)
            ncp.Entries[i] = Color.FromArgb(255, i, i, i);
        b.Palette = ncp;
```

When I use this palette, this time, image becomes Grayscale.

I just want to get clear RGB image.

**EDIT 2**

My camera's pixel format is BayerBG8. I dont know if it helps.

Comment: GDI+ uses BGR order. Maybe you just need to swap blue and red?

Comment: Not sure but looks like the color is inverted.

Comment: @DanByström I don't know how to do it. I have only pixel data.

Comment: 8-bit bitmap has a color palettet. The palette size should be 256 * 4. But then again, it's unusual that a high resolution camera would use 8-bit bitmap. Maybe it's 24-bit `size = (width * 3 + padding) * height` - show what the real image is supposed to look like.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I have a color palette with size of 256. After your comment, I tried to extend it to 4*256=1024, It throwed ArgumentException and exception says, palette cannot bigger than 255 and cannot less than 0. Camera's own library shows image correctly with same data with IGrabResult.Display();  code. But I couldn't. I am really really stuck in here.

Comment: It's 256 color. Each color is usually 4 bytes, so the size in bytes is 1024. I don't see anything relating to palette/color-table in the code you have shown.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I have edited the code with my palette.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

8-bit bitmap only uses 256 colors, it's not useful in any modern camera. The colors have to be supplied by whoever made the image. Each pixel is one byte (or 8-bits), it's a value from 0 to 256, it refers not to a color, but to an index in the color table.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)//change to 256
    ncp.Entries[i] = Color.FromArgb(255, i, i, i);
```

This basically makes a random color table. The odds that it's the right color table is 1/(256*256*256)

---

BayerBG8 is raw format, it has nothing to do with 8-bit bitmap. See [description](http://www.siliconimaging.com/Specifications/AN3%20-%20Bayer%20Color%20Processing.PDF)

Each pixel is represented with 4 color detectors. There are only 3 colors for each pixel, so they put an extra Green detector.

The first row is blue green blue green ...
The next row is green red green red ...

```
BGBGBGBG...
GRGRGRGR...
BGBGBGBG...
GRGRGRGR...
```

You have to take a 2x2 square and get an average color, representing 1 pixel:

```
piexel 1: BG    piexel 2: BG ...
          GR              GR ...
```

Starting from 3840x2748, you end up with 1920x1374 pixels.

Each color can be represented with 3 bytes. Now you have:

```
BGR BGR BGR BGR BGR BGR //RGB is stored backward as BGR
```

That's a total of 5760 * 1374 bytes. The example below uses a simple approximation. There are two green values for each pixel, we take an average of the two green values.

```
int src_width = 3840;
int src_height = 2748;

int dst_width = src_width / 2;
int dst_height = src_height / 2;

byte[] destination = new byte[dst_width * dst_height * 3];
int pos = 0;
for(int row = 0; row < src_height; row += 2)
{
    for(int col = 0; col < src_width; col += 2)
    {
        int i = row * src_width + col;
        //blue from this line
        destination[pos++] = source[i];

        //green average of two greens from this line and next line:
        destination[pos++] = (source[i + 1] + source[i + src_width])/2;

        //red from the next line
        destination[pos++] = source[i + src_width + 1];
    }
}
```

Use `destination` with `Format24bppRgb`, size 1920x1374

Comment: Finally I get the RGB image thank you so so much. When I save images from its own program, it saves with 3840x2748 dimension. I have googled and found that 

https://www.baslerweb.com/en/sales-support/knowledge-base/frequently-asked-questions/bayer-to-rgb-and-missed-pixel-value-at-last-row-and-line/15245/

I think we are losing half of pixels by your algorithm. What do you suggest?

Comment: I updated the algorithm to use all the data from raw image. I don't know what the final image looks like. It probably needs additional color correction, anti-aliasing, etc. which you can do in .net

Comment: @FurkanKESKIN Yeah, Bayer works with a sliding window, not just with 2x2 blocks. It moves, both in X and Y, by a single byte, meaning your final result is only one pixel less than the original amount of bytes. I answered a similar question before that also turned out to be about Bayer; you can check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50038800/395685).