# How to convert DIB to Bitmap in .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, system.drawing, dib

How do I properly retrieve a Device Independent Bitmap(DIB) pointer as a Bitmap in C# ASP.NET Core 3.1?

**Issue:** When I attempt to save a Bitmap from a Dib pointer, I receive *System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory"*

I'm using the following constructor
[Bitmap(Int32, Int32, Int32, PixelFormat, IntPtr)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#System_Drawing_Bitmap__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Drawing_Imaging_PixelFormat_System_IntPtr_) with the assumption that the final parameter can use the DIB pointer.

```cs
using System.Drawing.Common.dll
Bitmap(Int32, Int32, Int32, PixelFormat, IntPtr)
```

Using the following syntax:

```cs
    public class Example
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr GlobalLock(int handle);
            
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185944/why-must-stride-in-the-system-drawing-bitmap-constructor-be-a-multiple-of-4
        public void GetStride(int width, PixelFormat format, ref int stride, ref int bytesPerPixel)
        {
            int bitsPerPixel = System.Drawing.Image.GetPixelFormatSize(format);
            bytesPerPixel = (bitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;
            stride = 4 * ((width * bytesPerPixel + 3) / 4);
        }
        public Bitmap ConvertDibToBitmap(IntPtr dib)
        {
            IntPtr dibPtr = GlobalLock(dib);

            BITMAPINFOHEADER bmi = (BITMAPINFOHEADER)Marshal.PtrToStructure(dibPtr, typeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));
            /*
                biBitCount: 24
                biClrImportant: 0
                biClrUsed: 0
                biCompression: 0
                biHeight: 2219
                biPlanes: 1
                biSize: 40
                biSizeImage: 12058624
                biWidth: 1704
                biXPelsPerMeter: 7874
                biYPelsPerMeter: 7874
            */

            //We're able to initalize the object here:
            Bitmap img = new Bitmap(bmi.biWidth, bmi.biHeight, stride, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb, dibPtr);
            img.Save("OutputTest.bmp");
            /*This line throws the exception "System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory"*/

        }
    }
```

I'm assuming the issue is in the calculation of stride and/or the pixel format.  I'm unsure of how to determine [PixelFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) from [BITMAPINFOHEADER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-bitmapinfoheader)